# Confusion about file offset in Win32 LockFileEx API

Tags: winapi, ntfs

According to the [`LockFileEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex) documentation, a file offset is specified in `lpOverlapped->Offset/OffsetHigh`. But when debugging `winword.exe` to analyze its file system behaviors, I see it calls `LockFileEx()` on a 122-byte file with `Offset=0xfffffffb` and `OffsetHigh=0xffffffff`, and the call completes successfully. Apparently this is not a valid offset, what does this mean?

Comment: I seriously doubt that WinWord would call `LockFileEx` with such an offset (`0xfffffffffffffffb` is `-5` if treated as a signed value, `18446744073709551611` as an `unsigned` value). I would suspect a flaw in your debugging before I suspect a flaw in WinWord.

Comment: now i suspect that -5 is 5 bytes back from end of file

Comment: that would make sense for a seek, but not a lock

Comment: I create a sample and test the `LockFileEx` function but it does not work as you say, can you provide reproducible code snippets so that we can find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Locking a region that goes beyond the current end-of-file position is not an error.

They could be using the lock as some kind of flag or for synchronization.